# How to restrict duplicate record using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I need to check the duplicate value from database using PHP and MySQL.I am explaining my table below.

```
time_id        member_id     day_id      time

  1                2            1        12.30am-3.00am
```

Here I need to check duplicate for `time` column. Suppose user entered time like `2.00am-4.00am` for `member_id=2` and `day_id=1` it should be checked because `12.00am-3.00am` slot has already booked for that `member_id and day_id`.

Here I need query for user can not insert the time in between `12.00am-3.00am`  again for the same `member_id and day_id`.

Comment: Why you have not used two columns like `start time` and `end time` which include date too? It would have been easy with queries to check duplicate and crossing slots.

Comment: True, but either way, this isn't so hard

Comment: You can add unique constraint on these 3 column

Answer (score 4):

It will be much more easier (and better for data consistency) if you change `time` column to 2 columns `datetime` (ex. `date_start` and `date_end`), and then you can try built-in mechanisms in SQL to check that user try add some row between this two dates.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the logic steps you need to take to complete this task:

**Step 1** Separate the start time and end time into two columns. So your table should look like this:

```
time_id  member_id  entry_day    time_in                 time_out
1        2          2016-01-19   2016-08-19 12:30:00     2016-08-18 03:00:00
```

Your columns types should be:

```
`time_id`: `int`
`member_id`: `int`
`time_in`: `DATETIME`
`entry_day`: `DATE`
`time_out`: `DATETIME`
```

**Step 2** Write some PHP that executes a query on the database that looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TimeEntryTable t
WHERE t.member_id = :memberId 
AND :new_entry_time_in BETWEEN t.time_in AND t.time_out
OR :new_entry_time_out BETWEEN t.time_in AND t.time_out
```

> You will need to pass the new record's `time_in`, `time_out`, `member_id` to the query. I assume you're using PDO... if not then you should probably start.

**Step 3**

Check the result returned by that query.

```
if (count($resultsArray) === 0) {
    //Create the new record, 
} else {
    //If you're here than there was a record within that time range and you should not create it.  
}
```

Comment: But i have two field whose datatype is string.Are they work in my case ?

Comment: You will need to convert them, but they will work. Php will convert them for you. `$inTime = new \DateTime($inTimeString);` If you're using `PDO` you can submit that object as the parameter.

Comment: @ Layton Everson : I am using `jquery` timepicker for selecting the time in front end, Will it be good to save datetime type column.

Comment: Yes. If you think about it, no matter what you're using on the front end, you are ultimately submitting a string, It needs to be converted on the backend. I could write a book about why you shouldn't store the data in the database a string.

Comment: @subhra, this will be a little extra work now and a bit of a learning curve for you but it will be worth it to follow through. You will learn a lot of essentials by completing this task properly.